How to mark a DRF ViewSet action as being exempt from the application of a custom middleware?
I've created a Custom Django Middleware and added to the MIDDLEWARE settings variable correctly.
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class MyCustomMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # Perform some internal actions on the `request` object.
        return None

Since this is applied to all DRF ViewSets by default, I would like to exempt some actions that don't need this check. The idea would be to check a flag inside the process_view function taking inspiration from the Django CsrfViewMiddleware which checks if the csrf_exempt variable has been set by the csrf_exempt decorator. So I modified the custom middleware and created a custom decorator to exempt views explicitly.
from functools import wraps
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class MyCustomMiddleware:
    ...
    
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if getattr(view_func, "some_condition", False):
            return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden on custom middleware")
        # Perform some internal actions on the `request` object.
        return None

def custom_middleware_exempt(view_func):

    @wraps(view_func)
    def _view_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    _view_wrapper.some_condition = True
    return _view_wrapper

Having this I do something like this and it correctly enters the custom decorator before going inside the Django middleware.
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    @custom_middleware_exempt
    def my_action(self, request):
        return Response()

So far so good until I noticed that the view_func of the custom middleware process_view doesn't correspond to the action function (which is being decorated) but to the ViewSet function.
Inside the decorator: view_func = <function MyViewSet.my_action at 0x79ee9c471760>
Inside the middleware: view_func = <function MyViewSet at 0x79ee9c49c220>
Apparently, Django middlewares are applied at viewset level instead of action level. As a consequence view_func doesn't have the some_condition attribute set.
Is there a way to decorate a viewset action and change the viewset level function or an alternative way to achieve what I'm trying to do?
